# How to prove that an analytic function must be zero on the unit disk if zero on an arc of the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:let $f(z)$ be continuous on the closed unit disk, $\{z: |z|\leq 1\}$, and analytic on the open unit disk, $\{z: |z|<1 \}$, with $f(e^{it})=0$ for $0\leq t \leq \pi/4$. Prove that $f(z)=0$ on the open unit disk.

I try to apply maximum modules principle but I couldnt get the result. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $g(z)= \prod_{k=0}^7 f(e^{ki\pi/4}z).$

Comment: Is the exponent of e $k \pi i /4$, I mean there is an i in the exponent? So this new function g will have absolute value on the boundary of the disk that implies the absolute value of the function inside the disk is also zero hence g is zero on the open unit disk which than f is also zero on the open unit disk?

Comment: Thanks, yes I forgot the $i$, will put it in now.

Comment: So did I interpret your hint correctly? Thanks a lot.